# Can I use react hooks with a typescript class? (not with a React class, but a classic util typescript class?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can I use react hooks with a typescript class? (not with a React class, but a classic util typescript class?)

The case is that I have a lot of utils added into a class, and I need to add a useHistory to add navigation from a few of the functions.

Comment: You can use hooks inside Typescript **functions**, but not inside Typescript **classes**

Comment: React hooks are only valid in the body of functional components and other react hooks.

Comment: I understand the limitation for being in functional component only. But I don't understand the limitation of being part of a regular class that's not derived from React Component, or derived from anything. Any option to make it working? It is just an util class with no dependency by react.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why someone with experience in programming and web would vote negatively on this question. This is quite important option on large projects. I cannot see react hooks to survive the challenge of time if they don't provide support for classes. React with hooks, it's tooooo opinionated at this point.

Comment: You can, but only if this function is called on **every render** of the component. It will not work if the function that uses the hook is not called on **every single render unconditionally** of the component where you use it

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for posterity -- The option that I found was to create function (Function Component) that acts as a proxy. In the function I componse all the hooks I need and pass them as object to the Class.